# Jmeter reading parameters from csv, where number of parameters is not fixed

Tags: csv, jmeter

I'm new to jMeter. I need to pass parameters as an array of key-value pair. Sample parameter is shown below:

```
a:3:{i:2925107;i:1389339;i:2778927;i:1317197;i:2880395;i:1389407;}
```

Here the values 2925107, 2778927, 2880395 represents key and
1389339, 1317197 and 1389407 represents as their corresponding values.

Also, it will appear on the next lines of parameters as follows:

```
lease_ids[2925107]  1389339 
lease_ids[2778927]  1317197 
lease_ids[2880395]  1389407
```

Apart from this I also need to store some more parameters onto the csv.

I'm not sure how should I save it in csv file and how should I read it.

[Sample image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PLkA.png)

Comment: Are you passing a:3:{i:2925107;i:1389339;i:2778927;i:1317197;i:2880395;i:1389407;} this values from CSV??
OR are you getting this somewhere in you response 
if so Could you show snapshot of the response that contains a:3:{i:2925107;i:1389339;i:2778927;i:1317197;i:2880395;i:1389407;}
so that it  would be easy

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up your [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to have these lease IDs in form of:

   ```
   a:3:{i:2925107;i:1389339;i:2778927;i:1317197;i:2880395;i:1389407;}
   a:3:{i:2925108;i:1389340;i:2778928;i:1317198;i:2880396;i:1389408;}
   ```

   i.e. each entry on separate line. Use `id` as the "Variable Name"

   [image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config]
2. Remove all `lease_ids[xxxxxxx]` parameters from the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
3. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler
4. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def matches = (vars.get('id') =~ 'i:(\\d+)').findAll()

   for (int i = 0; i < matches.size() - 1; i++) {
       sampler.addArgument('lease_ids[' + matches.get(i).get(1) + ']', matches.get(i + 1).get(1))
   }
   ```
5. That's it, the JSR223 PreProcessor will automatically parse `id` variable and add the relevant `lease_ids` parameters to the request.

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)